# How to fire DataTableNewRowEvent after Rows.Add

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datatable, newrow

Now I have

```
var row = container.Tables[name].NewRow();
row[0] = time;
row[1] = val;
container.Tables[name].Rows.Add(row);
```

Of course event `DataTableNewRowEvent` is fired in first line. But I need fire them after last line, I mean after adding new row to `RowsCollection`. How to make it? I need it to get actual data in `DataTable` at the moment of firing `DataTableNewRowEvent`

I think about:

```
//to insert proper data
var row = container.Tables[name].NewRow();
row[0] = time;
row[1] = val;
container.Tables[name].Rows.Add(row);
//to fire event
container.Tables[name].Rows.Remove(container.Tables[name].NewRow());
```

but probably it's not best solution.

Comment: are you adding and removing the new row right away?

Comment: @Saint why can't you bind and unbind the event when you want ?

Comment: @Habib.OSU that is a very hacky way of programming.

Comment: @MonsterTruck, yeah but.. what are the other options ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you better handle the `RowChanged` event on `DataTable`, you'll get a parameter of type `DataRowChangeEventArgs` that has a `DataRowAction` property that let's you know the change that actually took place on the row, `Add` being one of the possible values.

Your handler would look like this

```
protected void DataTable_RowChanged(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == DataRowAction.Add)
    {
        // Do something with e.Row which is already populated
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about DataRowChangeEvent also refers to adding new row. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

DataTableNewRowEvent event is fired inside

```
protected virtual void OnTableNewRow(DataTableNewRowEventArgs e);
```

This method is called only in NewRow method of DataTable class. If you want to fire your event at a different time the only solution except inheriting DataTable class would be to use reflection.

```
MethodInfo mi = (typeof(DataTable)).GetMethod("OnTableNewRow", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// ...

mi.Invoke(container.Tables[name], new object[] { new DataTableNewRowEventArgs(row) }); // fire the event as you please
```